# phpunit errorexception after renaming command?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

When I run `phpunit` I get the following error message:

> Cannot declare class App\Console\Commands\ImportNewArtikel, because
>   the name is already in use

[image]

I do not understand this, all my other commands have a different name.

However, to get rid of the error, I decided to rename the file & class name to *Import**o**NewArtikel*. Now I get this error:

> ErrorException:
>   include(/home/www/pretty.dev/vendor/composer/../../app/Console/Commands/ImportNewArtikel.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

[image]

Why is he looking for `ImportNewArtikel.php`? I have renamed it. How can I run `phpunit`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to recreate the composer autoloader with this command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```